# "Canvas.node" not found in "ChartJs-node-canvas"

Tags: javascript, npm, canvas, server, chart.js

I want to extract a chart from `ChartJS` as an Image within NodeJS. I am currently using `chartjs-node-canvas` for this purpose. Using this package, I am able to generate images on my local machine (both windows10 - 64bit & ubuntu) but we are getting error on server (windows10 - 32bit). Please find an image of the error attached here [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMR42.png)

> error: Error: The specified module could not be found
>
> node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node

I have also checked under the `node_module` folder at that location and can find the file [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1Gt4.png)

I have removed `package-lock.json` & `node_modules` and then reinstalled all packages, but the error still persists.

Comment: Have you run npm install on the server for this project

Comment: Yes I run npm install on server @nunespascal

Comment: Any errors during the installation? The error is very clear that node module is missing.

Comment: We are getting warnings during the npm installation. Please check attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQab5.png)

Comment: You are using node-gyp. That has a few dependencies on windows. Refer: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-138276692. You need to make sure node gyp can compile correctly if you have that dependency.

Comment: Thank you @nunespascal,
I will check this solution.